# "depends libdrat-dev but it is not going to be installed" when trying to install gazebo humble

Tags: gazebo, ros2, installation

[image]

I had tried to install libdrat-dev but it didn't work

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, NAM. Please copy/paste the text and for errors instead of posting images of errors. When you say you tried installing `libdrat-dev` but it didn't work, what didn't work? I would bet you got a *different* error message that another library won't be installed. If you try installing that, you'll get **another** error message, etc., until you finally get down to the underlying conflict. A similar problem was discussed [here on the ROS Answers site](https://answers.ros.org/question/279780/unmet-dependencies-for-ros-desktop-full/)

Comment: I believe this question is a duplicate of another and I'll close this with a link to the other question.

Comment: Sorry about that. This is the first time i aks a question in a forum. I has seen the site you gave but I can't find the way to fix that error. Can you show me with this error:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdart6.13-external-convhull-3d-dev : Breaks: libdart-external-convhull-3d-dev (< 6.14.0) but 6.12.1+dfsg4-11build2 is to be installed
 libdart6.13-external-odelcpsolver-dev : Breaks: libdart-external-odelcpsolver-dev (< 6.14.0) but 6.12.1+dfsg4-11build2 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Comment: You have to keep trying to install the next named item until eventually you get to the root of the conflict. Once you resolve that then you can work your way back up again.